# Why won't my VSS2017 publish profiles show up as changes for pushing to source control

Tags: git, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, bitbucket-server

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I am trying to automate my build and publish. I am using a BitBucket Server for the repository and Bamboo for the build server.

In VS2017, on my local dev computer, I can create a new FileFolder publish profile, which gets created in the "My Project\PublishProfiles" folder below the project folder in my solution.

However, when I switch to Team Explorer and select changes, the new FolderProfile.pubxml file is not listed and so it doesn't get pushed up to BitBucket repo during commits and as a result, it is not available to the build server and so my Bamboo plan fails.

I tried creating a new folder for the project and copying the FolderProfile.pubxml file to that folder. Again, the solution builds and the project publishes as expected, but the new folder along with the FolderProfile.pubxml file does not show up in changes in Team Explorer and so it doesn't get pushed up to the BitBucket repo during commits and as a result, it is not available to the build server and so my Bamboo plan fails still.

If I add an empty test.cs file to the newly created folder profile folder, then the test.cs file and the newly created publish profile folder shows up in the changes for a commit but the FolderProfile.pubxml file that is also in that newly created folder does not show up in the changes.

So, it seems as though something in VS2017 is filtering out *.pubxml files from commits.

This is what the FolderProfile.pubxml file looks like, if it is relevant;

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\Dev\CDService\Output</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I am using the Visual Studio BitBucket Extension by NextIteration, if that is relevant.

Comment: I guess *.pubxml is ignored in the source control. Also I believe it's ignored by default on asp.net publishing.

Comment: Is there any way to override that, if it is a default? I looked in VS2017 options but didn't see anything that stood out

Comment: @Andy Your comment led me to a solution. Do you want to post as an Answer so I can accept it? Otherwise, I will Answer it myself so I can close out this question and detail the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*.pubxml is ignored in the source control. Also it's ignored by default on asp.net publishing. So check your config and make sure it's not ignored.

Comment: I am using BitBucket as my source control. I ended up going to Team Explorer in VS2017, click on the Home icon and select Settings. Then select Repository Settings and I did a search for .pubxml and found it was listed. I commented that line out. The settings section repository settings works with a .gitIgnore file and that is what was blocking the publish profiles form copying over to source control. Once I commented it out, the FolderProfile.pubxml file copied to source control.